# How can I make a map-marker's popupContent be a random phrase?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet.js to make a map and I need help with the javascript required to make a map-marker generate a random phrase with each click.

I've used this code to generate random text:

```
function randomText() {
var items = new Array(
            "Ow",
            "Stop poking me",
            "Stop",
            "Leave me alone",
            "Don't you have anything better to do?",
            "You're hurting me",
            "Go away"
);

var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);

return items[i];}
```

But when I try to put it in popup content it's blank.

I tried

```
.bindPopup(document.write(randomText()));
```

My current gist has `.bindPopup(randomText());` because it is, at least, not blank and  generates a random phrase with each page load.

Here is my gist https://gist.github.com/joshuahouston/800cd59aab26c264f3bc

And the working map with where I'm currently stuck http://bl.ocks.org/joshuahouston/800cd59aab26c264f3bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
function bindNewPopup(){
    this.bindPopup(randomText());
}
var marker = L.marker([47.16, -115.32])
        .on('click', bindNewPopup)
        .addTo(map);
```

The code in your gist only gets a randomText() when the marker is created. To change the text on every click, you need some way to call the function again; therefore create the function bindNewPopup.